# Hacking HoneyTab

Tags: rooting

I found this strange "anonymous" device: [HoneyTab](http://www.ankaka.com/honeytab-h3-android-30-honeycomb-tablet-multitouch-101-capacitive-screen-1ghz-dual-core-cpu-1080p-hdmi-output-wifi_p48068.html).

Never wishing to discuss whether it's worth to buy or not (it would be totally OT), my questions are simple and straight: does somebody know if this tablet can be rooted or not? Does somebody know if and how is it possible to upgrade its ROM to future versions of Android or just to modded ROMs?

I have little experience with HTC devices only but I never really understood if the same ROM can be used with multiple devices, and if rooting is a standardized procedure or not (I have Android on SD on my HD2, so it's rooted already)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) contains our collective knowledge on what devices can be rooted, with links to methods.  It's incomplete, of course, so if anyone knows how to root this tablet please add the info to the answer there, even if you post it here.

ROMs cannot generally be used with multiple devices.  Each device normally requires its own drivers and kernel, due to different hardware.

Rooting is also not standardized; it depends on how Android has been modified on your particular device, as well as how your bootloader behaves.  There are, however, methods of rooting that take advantage of exploits common to most flavors of a particular version of Android.  For example, "Gingerbreak" worked on most devices that had the original version of Android 2.3.  [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) contains a list of those generalized tools as well.

The device looks like it's not Google-certified, and from searching around it looks like very few people have it.  Information on it will be sparse and rooting that much harder if none of the common exploits work.

Comment: Has Honeycomb 3.2 been rooted yet, at least?

Comment: http://www.acertabletforum.com/forum/acer-iconia-tab-a500-help/1287-root-a501-honeycomb-3-2-a.html# looks like it's **not yet** rootable as of today

Comment: @djechelon Oops, I misread your first comment.  There are methods for rooting the Motorola Xoom on 3.2, and some other devices, but they look to be device-specific.  So I would guess that a general exploit for 3.2 has not been found, you're right.